# Firefox throws an error message through WebDriverManager

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefoxdriver

Firefox is mostly working, but the last test case failed - it won't click on an element.

`unable to read VR Path Registry` is the error message.

In Internet Explorer, it loads the browser, sometimes runs whole scripts (one issue though, where it opens in a different tab), and sometimes it runs one or two test cases.

Refer to code for Firefox, and also there is an issue with IE.

**Code:**

```
WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().version("0.21.0").setup(); 
driver=new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: what is your Firefox version?

Comment: 66.03 is the firefox version

Comment: match your versions from (https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/Support.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this-

```
WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().version("0.19.1").setup();
```

Comment: getting the same result

Comment: match your version control from above link